# SHGetDesktopFolder() doesn't return the file system root

Tags: windows, shell, directory, root, desktop

Following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetdesktopfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN), calling the SHGetDesktopFolder() function should return the file system root:

> Retrieves the IShellFolder interface for the desktop folder, which is
> **the root of the Shell's namespace**.

So I ran the following code:

```cpp
void LogDesktopFolderContent()
{
    IShellFolder* pDesktopFolder = nullptr;

    // get the desktop folder
    HRESULT hr = ::SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktopFolder);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;

    IEnumIDList* pEnumIDList;

    // list its content
    hr = pDesktopFolder->EnumObjects(nullptr, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &pEnumIDList);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pDesktopFolder->Release();
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        LPITEMIDLIST pItem;
        hr = pEnumIDList->Next(1, &pItem, nullptr);

        if (pItem)
        {
            wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];

            if (::SHGetPathFromIDListW(pItem, buffer))
            {
                ::OutputDebugString(buffer);
                ::OutputDebugString(L"\r\n");
            }

            ::CoTaskMemFree(pItem);
        }

        if (hr != S_OK)
            break;
    } while (1);

    pDesktopFolder->Release();
}
```

As a result, I get these files:

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\StartSystem.bat

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Private dev.lnk

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Rad Studio Common Dir.lnk

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\raw_registry_connections.png

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\The Alien Cube.url

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Tormented Souls.url

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Notes.txt

Well, this is the content of my **Desktop folder**. But **THIS IS NOT THE ROOT OF MY FILE SYSTEM**.

So, what I'm doing wrong, or what is the correct manner to get the file system root with the Shell API?

Comment: The files on your desktop are a bit special since they are in the root (virtually) and somewhere inside c:\users\....

Comment: This seems to be a matter of simply not reading the documentation. The documentation explicitly states that the root returned is the **shell** root, i.e. not any particular **file system** root (each filesystem has its own root, so which one would it return? `C:\` is not special)

Answer (score 1):

It is the root. `c:\Windows\Notepad.exe` for example is located at `(Desktop)\This PC\c:\Windows\Notepad.exe` in the shell namespace.

One problem is that "This PC" is a folder and you are asking for nonfolders. Another problem is that you are calling `SHGetPathFromIDListW` and this only works on things that have filesystem paths and "This PC" does not. To walk the namespace you should only use IShellFolder+pidl and/or IShellItem. To get the "real" name of an item, call `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf` and ask for `SHGDN_FORPARSING`.